# multiplying two columns, displaying as new column in select statement sql

Tags: mysql

trying to take values from two columns, multiply them, and display the result as a new column in, all in a select statement. Below is what I got so far

```
select m.item_name, m.price, sum(od.qty) as count
from menu as m, order_detail as od, sum(m.price * od.qty) as tsales
where m.menuid = od.menuid
group by m.item_name
order by count desc
limit 10;
```

I can get the select statement to do everything BUT show the new column with the new values.  Without the last part of the select statement it does this:

[select statement result without extra column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJtkj.png)
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjc81.png)

Comment: and what do you expect instead? do you miss the `tsales` column?

Comment: well I just get an error, I'm not sure how to show the new column with the info of two other columns in it

Comment: Well show us the error message.

Comment: Are you allowed to put a calculation in a section of SQL code that is ment for table names?

Comment: I'm not sure, that was sort of a stab in the dark

Comment: I think this is just a typo. try putting `sum(m.price * od.qty) as tsales` in the select list and not the table list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we are looking for a result that would be returned from a statement like this:

```
  SELECT m.item_name
       , SUM(m.price*od.qty) AS tot_price_times_qty
    FROM menu m
    JOIN order_detail od
      ON od.menuid = m.menuid
   GROUP BY m.item_name
   ORDER BY tot_price_times_qty DESC
   LIMIT 10
```

But, without any sample data or demonstration of expected output, that's only a guess.

Comment: YES! i had to rework it a little bit to display the results the right way but you nailed it thanks alot